# Django CSS is displayed different on local and production environment

Tags: python, html, django

Edit Form is not editable on production and the image button in the left, while on development it is editable and image button on the right.

What could be the issue?

The code is exactly the same. Checked on Chrome, IE and Firefox - same issue

Cleaned cache - didn't help.

Comment: Your question is way too broad, there's no way we can answer it. So you'll have to dig some more into the issue yourself and ask a more precise question. Look at [Ask] to learn how to formulate specific, good questions on SO.

Comment: And start by looking in your browser's developer tools to see the source code, the css attributes of each element etc... That should be the first thing to check so you know where the style of your page is coming from.

Comment: If the problem was in style, it was displayed the same way on both development and production, no?

Comment: There are differences so for sure the style/source is different. By looking in the debugger tools you can see where the style comes from. Maybe the style sheet can’t be loaded at all.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I applied the collectstatic command on production, instead of overwriting the previous css file I had it instead appended the additional code from the new css file.

You can use the browser development tool's 'Network' tab to see each file being loaded (css and javascript) and double click them to see if the content of those files matches the content you are expecting to see!